# is it possible to get Visual studio to index source code to improve string search?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, indexing

I often use the string search feature for an entire solution in VS2008. Is there a way to improve its search speed by getting VS2008 to index all the source code and config files, similar to how Google Desktop index files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I don't think it is possible to do within visual studio you may want to use [WinGrep](http://www.wingrep.com/), or another grep tool to do this sort of search instead.

Answer (score 3):

This adds instant full text search of all files in a VS solution.

Not free but cheap and is well worth the money.  30 day trial.

http://entrian.com/source-search/

Remap Ctrl+Shift+F to Entrian's Activate and you get what VS's Find in Files always should have been.

I'm using it in VS 2010, it says it works with 2005 and 2008 as well.

(I have no affiliation with the company).

Comment: also exists in new Resharper versions

Answer (score 1):

This is not a supported feature of Visual Studio.  The find in files feature simply goes through the files searching for the specified text and does not take advantage of any indexing.

It is possible to search using other 3rd party components using and indexed database though.

Answer (score 0):

I like searching using a tool called WildReplace .