# Is there a way to quickly find files in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Does Visual Studio 2010 have a built-in way to quickly find/open files, similar to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> function in Eclipse?

Or does ReSharper offer this functionality?

Comment: Yes ctl+shift+t in R# is even better.

Comment: or Ctrl+COMMA in C# which equates to Edit.NavigateTo

Answer (score 462, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

I'm surprised no one gave the right answer:

> Navigate To can show you a list of open files and lots more.
>   http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/21/searching-and-navigating-code-in-vs-2010-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

CTRL+COMMA is your friend.

Comment: It can bring back more than you want sometimes but that can be helpful. For instance today, I knew we had a ValidateDate method for validating dates we insert into our DB but wasn't sure where it was. Ctrl+, and type ValidateDate and instantly saw it was in our AbstractDAO.vb

Comment: Moreover, it understands FCLN (FirstCapitalLetterNotation). For example, to find ValidateDate, just type VD

Comment: Very useful, cheers...
I'm using vb and for some reason I had to reset the keyboard mappings (to Visual Studio C# 2005) for this to work - Tools/Options/Keyboard/Apply the following additional..

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I just don't understand why they didn't have the uncommon-sense to keep a 'search' option for the user when right-clicking on the solution.

Comment: I too had to add the shortcut myself as it was not assigned to edit.navigateto but now works a treat. only problem is i wish it could search with case insensitive

Comment: For anybody trying to do this in the Express edition, this feature is only available in the paid version of Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: In case you've lost your shortcut: Pre VS2017, it's under Tools, Options, Keyboard >>> `Edit.NavigateTo`. In 2017, that's moved to `Edit.GoToAll` ([hat tip](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43760342/1028230))

Comment: this doesnt work for visual studio code - Ctrl+, opens setting.
I just saw you can Ctrl+Shft+F

Answer (score 43):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> opens the command window, type "open" then start typing file names and it will dynamically autocomplete by available solution file name.

Comment: Not ideal but useful. Thanks.

Comment: to shorten the typing the alias for opening files "of" can also be used instead of "open". For more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3a0kd3x.aspx

Comment: This is the winner for me!

Answer (score 16):

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> to jump to the command bar (same as the search box, but with a > prefixed in the text).  I then type "of" (for "open file") and start typing the name of the file to open.  Possibly matches are automatically displayed by VS.

I also found that when using ReSharper, the familiar Eclipse shortcut for Open Type (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) is mapped to ReSharper's GotoFile command.

Comment: thanks, now I know that "of" stands for "open file", I didn't even know it was an acronym :)

Answer (score 8):

There is also another way to find files in the Visual Studio 2010 might be useful for someone.

In the command box in visual studio toolbar type ">of " and start typing the file name it will prompt list. Note: This will only find the class not the pages try it for yourself.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

this addin will very usefule to quickly open files from visual studio by pressong CTRL + K + O

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/3eb2f230-2728-4d5f-b448-4c0b64154da7

Comment: @DimitriC: read the reviews of this and it's reported as being slow. An alternative (which I'm the author of) - [VSFileNav](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cfdf85c2-aaa4-4bdd-b8ea-e22bcc9860af)

Comment: @Ian, - I've used it often (and still do) and it is great in my opinion.

Comment: Emm, the addin maybe [Quick Open File for Visual Studio 2010](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MartinKutny.QuickOpenFileforVisualStudio2010), which is the new link.

Answer (score 6):

In VS2017 or later versions, we have command called "**Edit.GoToAll**".

SO can configure it from VS tools.

see below snap.

[image]

I have configured my keys for file search as **CTRL + SHIFT + T**

Comment: GoToFile is better

Answer (score 4):

`CTRL+SHIFT+F` will bring open a find in files search dialog box.  The result will be listed, usually, on the lower section of VS in a Find Files result box.  Double clicking a result will open it

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+S doesn't do anything for me? And I really want something that searches as I type. There are several addons that do it for earlier versions of VS but I was hoping that MS included it in this version of VS.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+F opens "Find in Files".

Answer (score 4):

**DPack** has a dialog for finding files in the current solution (search all, or only open files), and it also has a dialog to search the current file for methods,properties, etc. Very nice! Note that the current version only supports VS 2012 or newer, but they have binaries there for older versions of VisualStudio as well:

http://www.usysware.com/dpack/

You could also try **Sonic File Finder**, which does something similar to CTRL+COMMA:

http://www.jens-schaller.de/sonic-tools/sonicfilefinder/overview/overview.htm

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse, Ctrl+Shift+O = "Organize Imports"... which I am not sure what this is. But it is not the Ctrl+Shift+F = Find in Files that is in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

[VSFileNav](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cfdf85c2-aaa4-4bdd-b8ea-e22bcc9860af) - An extension that I created that allow rapid file searching. It's basically got all the ReSharper functionality that was disabled in the express version of VS2010 (I used to really like this).

It's also free :)

Answer (score 2):

For file name search, I use the [Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.ProductivityPowerTools).
It adds a tab to Solution Explorer called "Solution Navigator".  It shows all the solution files in a tree and has a search bar at the top.

To search for text in all your solution files, use Entrian's Source Search:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9994522/24267

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com) comes with something like this. You will have to pay for the plugin (and I don't think you can use plugins in the express versions).

(If you're doing C++ and you don't plan to buy Visual Assist, be sure to never install the trial. It's that addictive.)

Answer (score 1):

I usually use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com) tool via a hotkey.

Answer (score 1):

For fuzzy search of files (and more) I needed to use <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

" ⌘ + P "

If someone's still looking for this for Mac and in 2023.

Additionally, here's a list of keyboard shortcuts from MS: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, VS doesn't offer this search-as-you-type functionality (and lots more).

Comment: This is not true. Look up Navigate To in VS 2010.

Comment: If you want to search just the current source file you also have Incremental Search CTRL+SHIFT+I which is a search as you type option.

Answer (score 0):

Type >open filename in the command box in the Visual studio can also open the file

Answer (score 0):

[NavigateToAll](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bdbc361a-ee69-4ba3-83ff-ab2e8122ff47) extends the built-in Navigate To by enabling you to open any file on the disk (not just the ones in the solution).

Answer (score 0):

CTRL + P, the right solution for me....

CTRL + , -> SETTINGS