# How to open a file quickly in visual studio .net

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-macros

In visual studio, we can open a file in a #Include statement by right clicking the filename in include statement and then clicking "Open Document". But sometimes, when I want to open a file, I don't remember where it was in the project or where has it been included. What I do is that I open any file, add a #include statement for that file, then right-click->Open Document to open the file and then remove the #include statement that I added just to open this file.

Can someone plz tell me a more straight forward way of quickly opening a file without searching for it?

I am using Visual Studio 2008

Comment: what version of VS are you using? As far I know, you can modify the Startup functionality of VS.

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667528/quick-find-files-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: I know what you mean. You want to navigate quickly to a standard header file but its buried in some folder structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to go to the "Find" combo box in the default toolbar, type `>of Foo.cpp` , and hit enter.  `of` is the "open file" command and will give you autocompletion with the files in your solution.

This also works for any other system or library header files you include (e.g. `windows.h`).

[image]

The leading `>` character tells the "Find" combo box to act like the Command Window, so any commands that work in the Command Window work in the combo box as well.

Comment: This doesnt work for me. There are some header files which are not included in the Visual Studio project but are found in include path. Using "Open Document" I am able to open those header files too but not using this method.

Comment: @binW: you can alternatively try `>Edit.OpenFile foo.cpp`.  If that works, you can create an alias for `Edit.OpenFile` with the `alias` command, e.g. `>alias ef Edit.OpenFile` and then `>ef foo.cpp`.

Comment: @binW: also look at the duplicate pointed out by @giddy.  If you're using VS2010, you can use Ctrl+, to bring up the "Navigate To" dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Assist X's "Open File in Solution" (command VAssistX.OpenFileInSolutionDialog) works great for quickly opening a file. I find it faster to use than Visual Studio's ">of" command.

See http://www.wholetomato.com/products/featureSearch.asp for a screenshot.