# How to Restore Navigate To Dialog in Visual Studio After Resharper Installation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper, resharper-7.1

After installing Resharper 7.1.2 for Visual Studio 2010, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> I no longer see the `Navigate To` dialog.  Instead a Resharper dialog `Recent Files` appears.  My question is, is there another key binding that I am not aware for the `Navigate To` dialog or how can I configure Resharper/VS to show the `Navigate To` dialog upon pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>.  In the Resharper options I have selected `Visual Studio` for the key bindings since that is what I am accustomed to, but for some reason this one has changed.

Comment: It happens to me after updating to the latest version of resharper. Have to fix it every time, very annoying.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

It sounds like you will need to remove the ReSharper keybinding and add the Visual Studio one again. Try the following:

From Visual Studio 2010, go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard.

In the textbox below "Show commands containing:" enter "gotorecent".

This should bring up one match and you can see the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> shortcut applied:

[image: Recent Files keybinding]

Click the `Remove` button. This should remove the keybinding.

In the textbox below "Show commands containing:" enter "edit.navigateto" (or for VS2017 "edit.gotoall").

This should bring up two matches. We are only concerned with the first one so make sure it is selected.

Click the texbox below "Press shortcut keys:" and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
[image: Navigate To keybinding]

Click the `Assign` button.

Click the `OK` button.

You may have to restart Visual Studio but that should do it.

**Edit:** Just in case it helps anyone else, in order to track down the command names, I exported the keyboard settings via Tools -> Import/Export settings -> Export selected environment settings -> select only Options -> Environment -> Keyboard.
In the resulting .vssettings file, the Command attribute of each Shortcut element contains the text that should be typed into the "Show commands containing:" textbox.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  This answer will be very useful to anyone with Resharper keybinding issues!

Comment: Perfect. Worked a charm

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017, you need to assign Ctrl+, to Edit.GoToAll (rather than Edit.NavigateTo).

Comment: All I did it was clicking in the Reset button and everything worked fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

It should be noted that the command for ReSharper's navigate to dialogue is "Ctrl + T"

Comment: ReSharper's *Navigate* menu lists both "Go to Everything / Type... (Ctrl+T)" and "Navigate To (Ctrl+,)". Maybe these are two different dialogs.

Comment: Go to Everything is one that is functionally similar to the original VS command, The navigate menu is just a hurdle imo.

Answer (score 14):

In Visual Studio 2017, you need to assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to **Edit.GoToAll** (rather than Edit.NavigateTo).

UPDATED:

Go to the Options->Environment->Keyboard, Make sure that (Default) is chosen in the top dropdown, type in Edit.GoToAll in the "Show comands..." textbox. Remove the existing shortcut. Type Ctrl+, in the "Press Shortcut Keys:" textbox. Click assign.

Comment: This answer eventually led me to discover how to fix this issue. A little more detail: Go to the Options->Environment->Keyboard, Make sure that (Default) is chosen in the top dropdown, type in Edit.GoToAll in the "Show comands..." textbox. Remove the existing shortcut. Type Ctrl+, in the "Press Shortcut Keys:" textbox. Click assign. Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

@Malice explained really well, but here is just one more tip:
When you are in the Keyboard Options menu, you don't need to export all commands in order to see which command corresponds to a particular shortcut, you can click on the "Press shortcut keys" text box and type your keyword to see what it is assigned to.

So you could:

- go to the Keyboard Options menu,
- type Ctrl+, to see what it is assigned to,
- unassign it,
- then type Ctrl+T to see what that "Navigate To" dialog is called within VS
- reassign that function to Ctrl+,