# Visual Studio 2012 - F12 into razor renderpartial stopped working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, razor, resharper-7.1

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with Resharper 7.
If I have a cshtml view where I render a partial view I could put my marker on the name of that partial view and press F12. That would take me to the file of the partial view.

Now that has suddenly stopped working and instead I get the documentation for C# string. What has happened?

Comment: Good luck: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285945/how-to-restore-navigate-to-dialog-in-visual-studio-after-resharper-installation