# F12 Visual Studio navigate to action from razor view doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio, razor, resharper

I've recently updated resharper and earlier I was able to navigate to controller action or razor view by pressing F12 when caret is placed on it's name. But now I get C# string documentation. Where and how can I restore this behavior? I've already found the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602882/visual-studio-2012-f12-into-razor-renderpartial-stopped-working) but there are no answers and suggested answer in comment to that question didn't help me.

Comment: What ReSharper and MVC nuget package versions do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I have just-code it's like resharper, in visual studio you can find menu named Just-Code then choose Options, you will see dialog search for Keyboard  Shortcut here you can select profile or see your shortcuts